# Issue with cvCvtColor (JavaCV + OpenCV)!

Tags: opencv, javacv

I use `cvFindContours` to find numbers segment in a number plate, it works great. After that, I want to convert it to grayscale (for OCR), I use `cvCvtColor` but it makes me so confused.

Plate image: 
[image]

Some number images I got (after `cvCvtColor`):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It's so strange, some work fine, but some not. Anyone can help me?

Oh, this is my code:

```
CvSeq contours = new CvSeq();
                IplImage contour_img = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize( plateImageGrey ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
                cvZero( contour_img );
                CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();                   
                cvFindContours( plateImageGrey, storage, contours, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );              
                while(contours != null)
                {
                    if(CV_IS_SEQ_CONTOUR(contours))
                    {
                        cvDrawContours( contour_img, contours, cvScalarAll(255), cvScalarAll(255), CV_C, CV_C, CV_C );
                        CvRect  boundingRect = cvBoundingRect(contours,1); 
                        if(((boundingRect.height()/boundingRect.width()) >=  2.0) && ((boundingRect.height()/boundingRect.width()) <=  3.0) && (area >= 1000))
                        {                           
                            CvRect cr = new CvRect(boundingRect.x() - 5 , boundingRect.y() - 5, boundingRect.width() + 10, boundingRect.height() + 10);                             
                            cvSetImageROI(plateImage, cr);                      
                            IplImage charImage = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(plateImage), plateImage.depth(), plateImage.nChannels());
                            cvCopy(plateImage, charImage);
                            cvResetImageROI(plateImage);

                            IplImage charImageGrey = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize( charImage ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
                            cvCvtColor( charImage, charImageGrey, CV_BGRA2GRAY);

                            Bitmap charImageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(charImageGrey.width(), charImageGrey.height(), Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
                            charImageBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(charImageGrey.getByteBuffer());
                            charImageBitmap = charImageBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                        }
                    }
                    contours = contours.h_next();           
                }
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Try showing `charImage` before `cvCvtColor`. Are they fine?

Comment: I tried, they are fine! So that's why I think it is issue of cvCvtColor!!

Comment: How many channels are there in `plateImage`?

Comment: `plateImage` is a 4 channels image. Do you think it's reason?

Comment: It might be. This kind of image corruption is usually a result of failure in estimation of width step. Try converting it to a 3 channel image.

Comment: Also check depth of `plateImage`. It should be 8u for each channel.

Comment: I guess the width in images that look fine is multiplies of 4.

Comment: I tried convert it to 3 channel, but it still corrupt! :|. I also checked depth, it's 8u.

Comment: Thank @wiggily, as you said, I set image's width is multiplies of 4, and now, it is working fine! Thanks again! :)

Comment: is there a specific reason why you are not using the new c++ api? anyway, i am interest in the problem, can you post an answer with the correct code?

Comment: Hi nkint, I'm working on Android project, so I use JavaCV [link](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/).
As wiggily said before, this kind of image corruption is usually a result of failure in estimation of width step, so I make width of images is multiplies of 4, that's all! :)